# "Object Moved To Here" ASP.NET MVC Redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, routes

I've tried other solutions (including manually setting the response) but I can't get rid of this message or redirect properly.

Explanation:
I have a hardware that comunicates with my "web api" to register new users. 
My web app is running behing a NoIP so every resource that gets accessed in 
http://my_public_domain:8082 is forwarded to http://my_internal_domain:80.

That being said, I have to build my routes using the overload of `Url.RouteUrl()` as I need full qualified routes intead of relative ones.

- `Url.RouteUrl("MyRoute")` generates the route http://my_internal_domain/MyRoute
- `Url.RouteUrl("MyRoute", dataValues, Request.Url.Scheme, hostName)` generates the route http://my_public_domain:8082/MyRoute (notice that I have to change the domain because of the dns)

The problem is that when I try to redirect to that route I get a page with the message **Object Moved To Here** and a link to that route. 
Initially I thought that this problem would happend only with external redirects, but if I just do a `Redirect("http://www.google.com.br")` for example I don't get this page.

I've tried to manually remove the response html body as sugested in another topic ([Response.Redirect results in "Object moved to here"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184596/response-redirect-results-in-object-moved-to-here)) but this do not solve the redirect problem and I only get a blank page.