# "Object moved to here" after download via postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, ssl

I'm getting a very confusing error on a site when I'm using IE 11. It's the ["Object moved to here"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184596/response-redirect-results-in-object-moved-to-here)-error.

[image]

I can only reproduce the error in IE, and in my production environment where I'm running on SSL.

**This is when it occurs:**

- The user clicks on a `LinkButton` which makes a postback to the server. The server responds with a stream of an Excel-file using `Response.BinaryWrite`, and is downloaded as an attachment. Page is not re-rendered since it's an attachment.
- The user clicks on another button which makes another postback, which returns a 302 with `Response.Redirect()`. Now I get the *"Object moved to here"*-error in IE.

**This is what confuses me:**

- Using the same code, I cannot reproduce it locally. Which could indicate that it has something to do with the certificate.
- It only occurs when the Excel-file is **xlsx**, but not the old format **xls**.
- If i use Fiddler to capture the traffic (using Fiddlers own certificate) it works fine even in IE.
- When I use Chrome, it works fine, which *could* indicate that it's not the server code. Or possibly it's just Chrome that's better at handling faulty behaviors from the server.
- If I don't download the Excel-file (using the postback), it works fine.
- It shouldn't be caused by `Response.Redirect(null)` because then Chrome wouldn't be able to handle it either.

**These are my guesses:**

- Because we send a postback to download the Excel-file without re-rendering the page the viewstate will be corrupt at the next postback.
- When I use Fiddler, it somehow helps IE to manage the problem.

I know the question opens up for speculation, but please be patient with me. I would share the code, but I cannot debug the code remote and I cannot reproduce it locally so I do not know what code to share... And it will be weeks before we can get new code up and running on the production server so I cannot add any more logging. **Any thoughts on what may cause the described behavior?**