Object moved to here Error in ASP.NET after github cherry pick
I am facing this issue of "Object moved to here." after I did cherry pick from previous commit in git from visual studio.
Then I got conflicts and I selected the current versions of the files. Project builds fine but on redirecting to every page I get this message. Also I checked the code, there is no change in redirect function.
What did I do wrong?
Any help is appreciated. (I am a beginner in github.)


Try adding logging to the Application_Error method in Global.asax to capture more information about the error. Also check out Dan Diplo's suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184596/response-redirect-results-in-object-moved-to-here

I have added the logs but there is no Error in Application_Error method. Also this object moved to here  error is coming on every page but after clicking on that message the page is opened, so According to Dan Diplo's suggestion, URL cannot be null right?
